# wxHaskell: resize layout to accommodate dynamic contents

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell, dynamic-ui

I am having some difficulty with dynamic layouts in wxHaskell. I have nested Panels, and the layout of the innermost panel often changes in a way that causes it to outgrow its parent's size.

I am unclear as to the purposes and effects of the various functions in Graphics.UI.WXCore.Layout that transform layouts, most specifically on `dynamic`, `stretch`, `expand`, `fill`, etc. Either an explanation of the functionalities provided by these functions, or a concrete example of how to allow for panels that resize based on the changing size of their contents.

I am using windowReLayout in the interim to manually update the layouts on events that trigger layout expansion, but I would assume that there is a more natural/elegant way of achieving the desired behavior.

---

As an aside, I am using WX through reactive-banana, but that shouldn't really change much about the layout behaviors of the widgets themselves.

Comment: I don't know of wxHaskell. I'd say all of Layout is based on wx sizers. See http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_sizer.html for how sizers work. A first idea can be got from "Programming with wxBoxSizer"

Comment: There is also some documentation in the source code which I found very helpful in the past: https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell/blob/8cf720e2721bf6622129a68c61bc8b5175e8b779/wxcore/src/haskell/Graphics/UI/WXCore/Layout.hs